# Unable to covert PEM to JKS

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, pem

I have  cert.pem, key.pem and ca.pem files to communicate Docker daemon over API call which is working fine. However I'm trying to covert key.pem file to .jks file which is'nt working. 
I tried with `https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html`
Also tried few commands found online like one given here `https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html`
Also tried the solution given here `https://github.com/tomcz/pemToJks`
but no go. Any help is appreciated.

We want jks file to import in a client from to make API call to Docker.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to modify the last instruction in the Oracle document, so that both the certificate and the key get stored in the same JKS file. The command names the destination as `keystore.ks`, replace that with `truststore.ks` (where the cert was placed earlier), so that the private key also goes into the same file.